# Edmx File is not showing Diagram for DB first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a Database , and I am proceeding with EF DB first approach .

```
Right click on Model folder
 --> select new item
 -->ADO.net Entity Data model. 
 then selecting the DB & finally clicking Finish.
```

After that I am not getting the Model Diagram of my DB. Not getting any Diagram for any of the tables.
**The Default view is ADO.net Entity Data model Designer**

Where is the issue? EF version is latest Stable(6.1.3).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vem1O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the tables?

https://magnusmontin.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/wizard2.png?w=590&h=515

Or remove ef and then later add your project

Comment: Did you try again add ef?

Comment: Yes, already tried but didn't worked, I have attached the screen shots, these are the auto generated codes error. I tried resolving & able to resolve 2 but the one of the error I am not able to resolve. Ideally these error shouldn't have there

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is that your current version of the asp.net web application form's entity framework does not match the entity framework version while you create your DB first model